# Converting images to .xcf format

Tags: image-processing, gimp, xcf

Is it possible to convert an image, or batch of images, to a .xcf or .psd file? Using ImageMagick's `convert` tool didn't work, but so far my attempts to look at doing this using gimp from the command line have been unsuccessful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An answer can now be [found here](http://www.gimptalk.com/forum/batch-convert-xcf-to-png--p358679.html#p358679). Put the following code into a script.

```
gimp -n -i -b - <<eof (let*="" (="" (file's="" (cadr="" (file-glob="" "*.png"="" 1)))="" (filename="" "")="" (image="" 0)="" (layer="" )="" (while="" (pair?="" file's)="" (set!="" image="" (car="" (gimp-file-load="" run-noninteractive="" file's))))="" layer="" (gimp-image-merge-visible-layers="" clip-to-image)))="" filename="" (string-append="" (substring="" 0="" (-="" (string-length="" file's))="" 4))="" ".xcf"))="" (gimp-file-save="" filename)="" (gimp-image-delete="" image)="" file's="" (cdr="" (gimp-quit="" eof<="" pre="">
```

enter code hereIt's a script that batch converts to any file format that gimp can read. Just substitute ".xcf" on line 2 and ".png" on line 6 for whatever file formats you need